# Not seeing custom error output using client_side_validations and formtastict

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic, client-side-validation

I can't seem to get the custom error display I would like, I've uncommented the text in config/initializers/client_side_validations.rb and created a rails.validations.actionView.js as described in the documentation but when debugging the form I can't seem to get the customized file to be used (I've also placed some breakpoints on the rails.validations.js file and it isn't hitting the add or remove there so perhaps that is the problem. All files are loaded through the asset pipeline and to my knowledge fully.

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.8'
gem 'formtastic'
gem 'client_side_validations' , '3.2.0'
gem 'client_side_validations-formtastic'
```

actionView.js

```
window.ClientSideValidations.formBuilders['ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder'] = {
add: function(element, settings, message) {
// custom add code here
console.log('added')
 },
remove: function(element, settings) {
console.log('removed');}}
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= semantic_form_for @sponsorship, :validate => true do |f| %>
  <%= f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :title, :hint => "Give us a title" %>
     <%= f.input :bio %>
    <%= f.input :blurb %>
    <%= f.input :category_id, :as => :select, :collection => Category.all, :label_method => :title %>
    <%= f.input :event_id, :as => :select, :collection => Event.all, :label_method => :title %>
    <%= f.input :date_end, :start_year => 2012, :as => :date_picker %>
    <%= f.input :funds_needed %>
    <%= f.input :user_id, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => current_user.id } %>
    <%= f.input :agree_to_terms %>
    <%= f.validate %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.actions do %>
    <%= f.action :submit, :as => :input %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

HTML Output in head

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/rails.validations.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/rails.validations.formtastic.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/rails.validations.customValidators.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/rails.validations.actionView.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

client_side_validation.rb

```
require 'client_side_validations/simple_form' if defined?(::SimpleForm)
require 'client_side_validations/formtastic'  if defined?(::Formtastic)

 ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
   unless html_tag =~ /^<label/
     %{<div class="toto"><div class="field_with_errors">#{html_tag}</div><label for="#{instance.send(:tag_id)}" class="message" style="float:right;">#{instance.error_message.first}</label></div>}.html_safe
   else
     %{<div class="toto">#{html_tag}</div>}.html_safe
   end
 end
```

I'm new to rails so I've probably gaffed somewhere. Any questions let me know! Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine. What happens if you throw a validate option on one of the individual fields? Does anything fire then?

Also, any errors in the console? I've found with client_side_validations that you need to ensure that the persistent messages are turned on in the console (specifically Chrome) so that they stick around post-form submission.